# Laravel 5.3 - Validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I'm trying validate my form specified for multi language.

```html
<form>
    <select name="test">
        <option value="1">YES</option>
        <option value="2">NO</option>
    </select>
 <input type="text" name="lorem[1]">
 <input type="text" name="ipsum[1]">
 
 <input type="text" name="lorem[2]">
 <input type="text" name="ipsum[2]">
</form>
```

I have the code to the validation like this

```html
$validator['test']  = "required|integer";
$validator['lorem.*']  = "required_with_all:ipsum.*|min:3";
$validator['ipsum.*']  = "required_with_all:lorem.*|min:3";
$this->validate($request, $validator);
```

Field 'lorem.*' must have value if the field 'ipsum.* have value and conversely.

Everything works fine except for one case.
If I don't fill any fields except 'test'.

It isn't good valid:

```
test = '1';
lorem[1] = '';
ipsum[1] = '';
lorem[2] = '';
lorem[2] = '';
```

How I can repair it?

Comment: What if you replace the `required_with_all:ipsum.*` with a regular `required`?

Comment: lorem[1] required if ipsum[1] is fill,
lorem[2] required if ipsum[2] is fill,

In my app one language must be filled, I don't want show which

Comment: You have to write custom validation. Cos,  just like you said it fails validation because you wrote it in such manner. Logically speaking, your requirement is lorem is required if ipsum is required, which means if ipsum is not filled then lorem need not to be filled and thus passes validation